# How to select data previous and next from data range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select data from range month. Example: `@month = 4`  then data from `15-03` to `15-05`. It's look work fine.

```
Wood    25-03-1990
Mary    10-04-1988
Brown   25-04-1989
White   10-05-1992
```

But, when i try `@month = 1` or `@month = 12` , data not found. This is data and snippet code

```
NAME    BIRTHDAY
John    10-11-1988
Green   25-11-1990
Black   25-12-1989
Blue    10-12-1991
Red     10-01-1992
Candy   25-01-1989
Food    10-02-1993
Apple   25-02-1988
Wood    25-03-1990
Meat    10-03-1991
Mary    10-04-1988
Brown   25-04-1989
White   10-05-1992
Yellow  25-05-1993
```

And SQL-T

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY,CONVERT(DATE,BIRTHDAY,105)))+'-'+
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH,CONVERT(DATE,BIRTHDAY,105)))+'-'+
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())),105) 
BETWEEN 

    CONVERT(DATE,'15'+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),
    --CASE 
    --     WHEN @month = 1 THEN '12' 
    --     WHEN @month = 12 THEN '11' 
    --     WHEN @month <> 1 AND @month <> 12 THEN @month-1
    --END 
    @month-1
    )+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())),105)
AND
    CONVERT(DATE,'15'+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),
    --CASE 
    --     WHEN @month = 1 THEN '2' 
    --     WHEN @month = 12 THEN '1' 
    --     WHEN @month <> 1 AND @month <> 12 THEN @month+1
    --END
    @month+1
    )+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())),105)
```

Comment: The code you've commented out is close.  But you're not changing the year when you go back to December or forward to January.  What version of SQL are you using?  You may be able to do something better using DATEADD and DATEFROMPARTS?  If you tell me the version of SQL you're targeting I can give you a full answer.

Comment: I use SQL server 2008 express .

Comment: Also what data type is BIRTHDAY in your table, is it a date or a varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the column as datetime would have made things easier but how about this:

```
declare @Month int
SELECT @Month =1
-- Get start of the period
declare @baseDate date
SELECT @baseDate = CONVERT(DATE,'15-'+CONVERT(char(2), @Month)+'-'+convert(varchar(4),YEAR(GETDATE())), 105)
Print @baseDate
declare @startDate date
SELECT @startDate = DATEADD(mm,-1, @baseDate)
PRINT @startDate
declare @endDate date
SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(mm,+1, @baseDate)
PRINT @endDate

SELECT *,DATEADD(yy, YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, birthday, 105)),CONVERT(date, birthday, 105)) FROM ABC
WHERE 
DATEADD(yy, YEAR(@StartDate)-YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, birthday, 105)),CONVERT(date, birthday, 105))
BETWEEN 
@StartDate AND @EndDate
OR
DATEADD(yy, YEAR(@EndDate)-YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, birthday, 105)),CONVERT(date, birthday, 105))
BETWEEN 
@StartDate AND @EndDate
```

** Edited to correct error when adjusting birthday to current year based on bug report from OP

Comment: Hi @OldBoyCoder, data lost some row. Example `@month = 1` data only range from month 1 and 15/2 , lost to 15/12 . `@month = 12` data only range from month 12 and 15/11 , lost to 15/01

Comment: You're right - I missed that, try the revised version.